# react-native + redux - Appending/adding json payload to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, redux

I want to add a new product detail json to my array cart.

**Here's my reducer**

```
 const initialState =  { cart: [] };

export default (state = initialState , action) => {     
    console.log('state', state);
 switch(action.type) {

    case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS :
    var newArr = state.cart.concat(action.payload);
     return {           
        ...state, cart : newArr     
    }    
    default : return state;

    }
}
```

**I have also tried another method**

```
 return {
         ...state, cart : [...state.cart , ...action.payload]
       }
```

Neither of the method is working

Comment: What actually in the `action.payload` ? Are there real array or some JSON ? If JSON, you probably need to parse it first `JSON.parse(action.payload)`

Comment: What do you mean by `neither of the method is working`? Try and be clear about what exactly isn't working.

Comment: I am not able to push the new data to the cart array.

Comment: `return { ...state, cart: [ ...state.card, action.payload ] }` - no need to spread the item you're adding

Comment: I tried it first. It didn't work either :/

Comment: you could console log to make sure `case FETCH_DATA_SUCCES` is reached, then you must make sure your payload is an array with `Array.isArray(...)`.